# Load FLAC file in python same as scipy or librosa

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, flac, librosa

I would like to feed some flac sound files into a keras model. With wavfiles I can do (contrived example with one audio file used twice)

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

path = 'path/to/file.wav'
_, audio = scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)
dataset = [audio, audio]
x_train = np.array(dataset)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 1], num_classes=2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=x_train[0].shape))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

How do I do this with flac files instead?

Comment: Just decode to wav (either using python; or externally; e.g. ffmpeg or the official decoder).

Comment: I'd prefer a programmatic solution, an explanation of what the librosa and scipy functions actually load and how to get a flac file to match that format. It's some numpy array?

Comment: You will get a match by decoding to wav, followed by reading through scipy (where the docs will give you constraints on the kind of wav-files). To be honest: except for toy-tasks, you eventually will need a more evolved pipeline doing this decoding once for later learning. As this data will be huge, you probably want some hdf5-based storage (or at least numpy's mmap). Additionally: from a ML-perspective, a raw wav-file based input will probably not help in your ML-tasks. That's what librosa is for (feature extraction)

Comment: How does wavenet fit into your last statement, afaik wavenet does not use mfcc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [soundfile](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/) package can load flac files in a numpy array compatible format

```
import numpy as np                                                             
import soundfile as sf                                                      
import keras                                                                
from keras.models import Sequential                                         
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation                         
from keras.optimizers import SGD                                            

path = 'path/to/file.flac'                                                  
data, samplerate = sf.read(path)                                            
dataset = [data, data]                                                      
x_train = np.array(dataset)                                                 
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 1], num_classes=2)                 

model = Sequential()                                                        
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=x_train[0].shape))       
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))                                   
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

forkable sscce https://www.kaggle.com/morenoh149/flac-keras-hello-world

Comment: the soundfile has many bugs it doesn't work any more, same as librosa because it based on soundfile, is there another way?

Comment: I don't know of a simpler way. If someone more knowledgable of numpy arrays could chime in that would be great.